# How to handle Python 3.x UnicodeDecodeError in Email package?

Tags: python, exception, unicode, python-3.x, python-unicode

I try to read an email from a file, like this:

```
import email
with open("xxx.eml") as f:
   msg = email.message_from_file(f)
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\fakt\real\maildecode.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "I:\fakt\real\maildecode.py", line 50, in main
    decode_file(infile, outfile)
  File "I:\fakt\real\maildecode.py", line 30, in decode_file
    msg = email.message_from_file(f)  #, policy=mypol
  File "C:\Python33\lib\email\__init__.py", line 56, in message_from_file
    return Parser(*args, **kws).parse(fp)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\email\parser.py", line 55, in parse
    data = fp.read(8192)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1920: character maps to <undefined>
```

The file contains a multipart email, where the part is encoded in UTF-8.  The file's content or encoding might be broken, but I have to handle it anyway.

How can I read the file, even if it has Unicode errors?  I cannot find the policy object `compat32` and there seems to be no way to handle an exception and let Python continue right where the exception occured.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test on your message, so I don't know if this will actually work, but you can do the string decoding yourself:

```
with open("xxx.eml", encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
    text = f.read()
    msg = email.message_from_string(f)
```

That's going to get you a lot of replacement characters if the message isn't actually in UTF-8. But if it's got `\x81` in it, UTF-8 is my guess.

Answer (score 6):

To parse an email message in Python 3 without unicode errors, read the file in binary mode and use the `email.message_from_binary_file(f)` (or `email.message_from_bytes(f.read())`) method to parse the content (see the [documentation of the email.parser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes)).

Here is code that parses a message in a way that is compatible with Python 2 and 3:

```
import email
with open("xxx.eml", "rb") as f:
    try:
        msg = email.message_from_binary_file(f)  # Python 3
    except AttributeError:
        msg = email.message_from_file(f)  # Python 2
```

(tested with Python 2.7.13 and Python 3.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('email.txt','rb') as f:
     ascii_txt = f.read().encode('ascii','backslashreplace')

with open('email.txt','w') as f:
     f.write(ascii_text)

#now do your processing stuff
```

I doubt it is the best way to handle this ... but its at least a way ...

Comment: Hmm - but I want to process it with the email package and not per se destroy all UTF-8 or whatever charset it's in.

Comment: try encode ('utf-8',"ignore") ... maybe? instead of  ('ascii').  but you would need to open the file to write with "wb"

Answer (score 0):

A method which works on python 3, which finds finds the encoding and reloads with the correct one.

```
msg=email.message_from_file(open('file.eml',  errors='replace'))
codes=[x for x in msg.get_charsets() if x!=None]
if len(codes)>=1 : 
    msg=email.message_from_file(open('file.eml', encoding=codes[0]))
```

I have tried with `msg.get_charset()`, but it sometimes answers `None` while another encoding is available, hence the slightly involved encoding detection